# R: Variable length differ

Tags: r, variables

I want to regress a differenced dependent variable on differenced independent variables and on one non- differenced variable.
I tried the following lines in R:

```
xt <- ts(xx)
yt <- ts(yy)
zt <- ts(zz)
bt <- ts(bb) 
mt <- ts(mm) 
xtd <- diff(xt) 
ytd <- diff(yt) 
ztd <- diff(zt) 
btd <- diff(bt) 
axx <- ts.intersect(xtd, ytd, ztd, btd, mt) 
reg1 <- lm(xtd~ytd+ztd+btd+mt, axx)
summary(reg1)
```

Without the command ts.intersect() a error message pops up, saying that the variable lengths differ, found for the variable mt. Which makes sense since it isnt differenced. My questions are:
i) is this a correct way to deal with different variable lengths? and ii) is there a more efficient way? many thanks in advance

```
Date    xx  yy  zz  bb  mm
1   03.01.2005  0.065   0.001   14.4700 17.938  345001.0
2   04.01.2005  0.067   0.006   14.5100 17.886  345001.0
3   05.01.2005  0.064   -0.007  14.4200 17.950  334001.0
4   06.01.2005  0.065   -0.005  13.8000 17.950  334001.0
5   07.01.2005  0.060   -0.006  13.5700 17.913  334001.0
6   10.01.2005  0.059   -0.007  12.9200 17.958  334001.0
7   11.01.2005  0.057   -0.009  13.6800 17.962  334001.0
8   12.01.2005  0.060   -0.005  14.0500 17.886  340001.0
9   13.01.2005  0.060   -0.004  13.6400 17.568  340001.0
10  14.01.2005  0.059   -0.005  13.5700 17.471  340001.0
11  17.01.2005  0.058   -0.005  13.2000 17.365  340001.0
12  18.01.2005  0.059   -0.005  13.1700 17.214  340001.0
13  19.01.2005  0.057   -0.006  13.6300 17.143  354501.0
14  20.01.2005  0.057   -0.007  14.1700 17.125  354501.0
15  21.01.2005  0.056   -0.007  13.9600 17.193  354501.0
16  24.01.2005  0.057   -0.006  14.1100 17.283  354501.0
17  25.01.2005  0.058   -0.006  13.6300 17.083  354501.0
18  26.01.2005  0.057   -0.006  13.3200 17.348  348001.0
19  27.01.2005  0.059   -0.005  12.4600 17.295  353001.0
20  28.01.2005  0.060   -0.004  12.8100 17.219  353001.0
21  31.01.2005  0.058   -0.004  12.7200 17.143  353001.0
22  01.02.2005  0.059   -0.003  12.3600 17.125  353001.0
23  02.02.2005  0.058   -0.003  12.2500 17.000  357501.0
24  03.02.2005  0.056   -0.008  12.3800 16.808  357501.0
25  04.02.2005  0.058   -0.004  11.6000 16.817  357501.0
26  07.02.2005  0.058   -0.004  11.9900 16.798  357501.0
27  08.02.2005  0.058   -0.003  11.9200 16.804  355501.0
28  09.02.2005  0.062   0.000   12.1900 16.589  355501.0
29  10.02.2005  0.060   0.000   12.0400 16.500  355501.0
30  11.02.2005  0.062   0.002   11.9900 16.429  355501.0
```

Comment: Do you have missing data in your data frame?

Comment: No, I checked for Na in my df by the following command: sum(is.na(df))

Comment: Try table(is.na(df)). Also, it'd be best if you could provide some data that reproduces this error

Comment: How would you propose that this should work.

Comment: thx I tried table(is.na(df)), it says: FALSE 59984. so I assume there are no NAs.  The error message only pops up if I do not use the command ts.intersect(). With this command there is no error  message. But I was wondering, if my approach is the right one to handle a regression with variables which have different lengths? Btw how do I upload a data sample? thx

Comment: Just paste a small set of your data formatted a code. More information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  What is the name of the dataframe that doesn't result from `ts.intersect`? You should run `table(is.na(xx))` on that...

Comment: I edited my original question and added a small set of data. somehow the headers of the data shifted. I hope this is no problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes you need to use `ts.intersect()` when you have some variables that are differenced and some that are not.

You can probably clean up the code a little bit so you don't have so many lines repeated but (especially if you these are all your variables it doesn't really make a difference.

For example, you might recode all columns as time.series in one step by doing `ts.d=ts(d[2:6])`.

Comment: many thanks! so I assume this will also work if I want to include lagged depent/independent variables?